# Win32 child control drawing question (InvalidateRect) (grey background)

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox, parent-child, repaint

my question is about how to properly repaint a child control after changing its text (in this case a checkbox).

**Important to tell**:

- the checkbox is subclassed and gets painted in WM_PAINT &
  WM_ERASEBKGND returns 1.
- Window **does not use** WS_EX_COMPOSITED, WS_EX_LAYERED or WS_CLIPCHILDREN.
- Checkbox **does not use** WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.

---

When I call InvalidateRect() on the checkbox, it has a grey background (**image 2**).

When on the other hand I call InvalidateRect() on the parent window, it behaves like I want to (**image 3**)

I think the second case works because also an *WM_PAINT* gets sent to the parent window instead of just *WM_ERASEBKGND*.

In the first case I don't understand why *WM_PAINT* doesn't get sent to its parent window **OR** why *WM_ERASEBKGND* does gets sent to the parent window.

**Conclusion**: To repaint a child control do you have to use InvalideRect() on the parent instead of the child?

---

*Edit: Turns out the parent window receives a WM_ERASEBKGND message after I call ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (::LPARAM)text.c_str()); on the checkbox. It was not because of the InvalidateRect() call on the checkbox.*

*I expect this is because of when you want to draw the checkbox inside the parent procedure. But why doesn't it then also generate a WM_PAINT for the parent window?*

[Initial Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AuRm.png)

[After calling InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, true) on the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcuoI.png)

[After calling InvalidateRect(::GetParent(hWnd), &checkboxRect, true) on the parent window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDhZF.png).

Comment: Please show [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be easier to follow.

Comment: And the parent window reacts in the correct way and returns the correct brush when WM_CTLCOLORBTN is sent by the Button?

Comment: @xMRi hey. I return a NULL_BRUSH in both WM_CTLCOLORBTN and WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC. But these messages don't matter if you custom paint right?

Comment: If you are using a null brush in the subclassed WM_ERASEBKGND it does not surprise me that it doesn't draw the way you want if the parent is not repainted.

Comment: NULL_BRUSH never works in such ways. Even if you find tons of links about that. It is simply wrong! The window below isn't painted first, when the child is repainted... in other words: the parent receives no message if the child is repainted...

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. @xMRi I debugged the code again and indeed you are right.. The parent window apparently receives a WM_ERASEBKGND message after I set the checkbox text with: ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (::LPARAM)text.c_str()); This is probably the reason why the background becomes grey because the window erases it but doesn't repaint itself because a WM_PAINT message is not generated along with that WM_ERASEBKGND.